# Was the Feeds guy sick in bed?

Tags: support, chat, feed

In the [C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) we have set up a few feeds, one to post all answers to the [C++ FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag). This used to work fairly well, the [Feeds guy](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2/feeds) posted anything that was subscribed to.

However, the other day I accidentally noted a [new answer (2011-06-23)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag/96201#96201) to the above mentioned question, surprisingly ***without*** the Feeds account posting anything. I was surprised, but forgot about the issue.

However, about 18 hours ago, about 2.5 days late, the Feeds guy finally got around [posting an announcement](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/909485#909485) of the new answer.

What happened? Was the Feeds guy sick in bed? Was that a one-time glitch or is the a systematic problem? Getting announcements 2.5 days late is like not getting any at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had some network issues in the New York data center over the past days, so my guess is that the feeds guy (he lives in Oregon with the rest of chat) was actually awake, but the RSS feed (living in New York) was <s>snoring in the corner</s> simply broken or unreachable everytime the chat tried to call.

It's hard to say this with certainty, but as long as this is an isolated incident, I'll take it as the most probable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Feeds was on the ball with another answer that got posted to that question- took him only 14 minutes to post it.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. This is about the delay I would have expected.